# Stretching field below another stretching field in the same group footer

Tags: jasper-reports

## Background

I have a report where the completed analyses are supposed to show below the outstanding work. I had the completed analyses set to float

[image]

If there is a lot of completed work, the field seems to stretch but does not print the information

[image]

I changed this completed analyses field to be fixed relative to top, and now it prints all of the information but overlaps if the Outstanding field expands

[image]

Thanks in advance for anybody who can help.

## SQL

```sql
create table analyses (ID int not null IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, info1 varchar(max), info2 varchar(max))

insert into analyses values ('short string', 'short string')
insert into analyses values ('Extremely long string which is so long that I don''t know how I can carry on thinking of things to write so I will just keep writing things like this until I get bored and eventually it will be long enough I think, well probably, not entirely sure','Extremely long string which is so long that I don''t know how I can carry on thinking of things to write so I will just keep writing things like this until I get bored and eventually it will be long enough I think, well probably, not entirely sure')
insert into analyses values ('another short string', 'another short string')
```

## JRXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.3.final using JasperReports Library version 5.0.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_3" pageWidth="400" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="360" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7f2b0070-ae21-43b8-aed2-2d97e01f5788">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from analyses]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Info1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Info2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="24">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="188" y="0" width="62" height="24" uuid="c63aa7bc-0916-4bc4-b00a-2b2f7e0ecdc1">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Info 1   +]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="251" y="0" width="68" height="24" forecolor="#EB3431" uuid="4915813a-f96b-4bd4-a278-5d51378419f5">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Info 2]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="188" height="24" uuid="94aa55be-e050-4488-933d-d29497fe1adb">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="24">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="185" height="12" uuid="5b4f1d89-0191-4607-bca5-715d3828bbaa">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="185" y="0" width="135" height="12" uuid="ac96f759-7c22-4877-afb1-a7529d61a067">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Info1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="185" y="12" width="135" height="12" forecolor="#EB221E" uuid="44747f9d-582d-4b46-a729-104a0f5c7eaa">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Info2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 'Completed' textfield:

- choose position type = 'Float'
- choose stretch type = 'No Stretch'
- make sure the 'Stretch with Overflow' option is checked (true)

Comment: This still just results in the expanded but empty field :(